# Abbreviation permutation in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm trying to write a small routine responsible for permuting all possible abbreviations for a string. This string is a full name, separated by spaces. Like this:

```
James Mitchell Rhodes
```

I want to output:

```
J. Mitchell Rhodes
James M. Rhodes
J. M. Rhodes
```

And so on... however, i also have to consider "stopwords":

```
James the Third Rhodes
```

I want to output:

```
J. the Third R.
James The Third R.
```

Is there a known algorithm for this? I've been trying to fix this problems for quite some time now.

**UPDATE: Having each word in array is dead easy. Just explode(' ', $string) and then array_map, to exclude the stop words considering in_array($word, $stopWordsMap). This is NOT the problem, and NOT the focus of the question. The problem is how to discover the combination of possible Original words (O) and Abbreviated words (A):**

```
O A A
O A O
O A A
A A A
O O O
```

Comment: No, there's not going to be a well-known algorithm for this as the solution is pretty trivial string manipulation.

Comment: Would you be kind to share your solution to such a trivial string manipulation?

Comment: explode on space, ignore the stop words, loop. does not sound to hard, where are you stuck

Comment: I think generating the permutation is "harder", not the string manipulation.

Comment: @Dagon I would do it in reverse order: remove the stop words, explode on space etc ;)

Comment: I'm stuck on permuting all the abbreviation possibilities. I don't think you actually understood the issue, Dagon. I need to output an array with all possibilites. For example, in a name with 3 parts (O = Original, A = Abbreviated): O O A, O A A, A A A, O A O, A O O, A A O

Comment: Sounds like a recursive loop then, skipping stop words . . .

Comment: Stop words are not the issue, permuting all O and A possibilities is.

Comment: Having each word in array is dead easy. Just explode(' ', $string) and then array_map, to exclude the stop words considering in_array($word, $stopWordsMap). This is NOT the problem, and NOT the focus of the question.

Comment: Check the updated question for more info. meagar, have you even read the question? Stop hijacking.

Comment: The question is not about permutation. A permutation solution can be easily found here: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch04_26.htm

If you understand the question and read it carefully, you will understand that this is about permuting on every possible combination, not a simple permuting task.

Answer (score 2):

First instinct is to iterate the binary permutations with a for loop, i.e., strip out stop words (remembering their positions if you wish), 2 ^ numOfRemainingElements, `AND` out the state (meaning abbreviated or not) for each word:

```
$names = array('James', 'Earl', 'Jones');
$nameCount = count($names);
$permCount = pow(2, $nameCount);

for ($p = 1; $p < $permCount; $p++) {
    for ($n = 0; $n < $nameCount; $n++) {
        echo $p & pow(2, $n) ? $names[$n][0] . '.' : $names[$n];
        echo ' ';
    }
    echo "\n";
}

/* output:

J. Earl Jones 
James E. Jones 
J. E. Jones 
James Earl J. 
J. Earl J. 
James E. J. 
J. E. J. 

*/
```

You can tweak it further but you can see where I'm going with it.

Comment: wow thats really elegant, third line should be $permCount = pow(2, $nameCount) and it's perfect.

Comment: @joschua011: Thanks for the compliment and the suggestion (which I've incorporated).

Answer (score 1):

I am not gonna write the full code, since you said permuting is not the issue. This is about figuring out which words to permute for all scenarios.

I had to think of the binary system, stay with me on this on xD if you want to have all the possible inputs to a function with n inputs, you need 2^n input scenarios.

so for you 2 inputs you wolud have

```
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
```

alright? we can get this as an array in php with

```
$map = array();
$inputs = 2;
for($i=0;$i<=2^$inputs;$i++){
    $bin = decbin($i);  // returns string
    $array = preg_split('//', $bin, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // but i want a array
    $map[] = $array;
}
```

Now if your string that you want to permute has three words, see them as three inputs, and then all the $map rows tell you which word to permute every time to get all possibly strings, if the first item in that row is 0, dont permute the first word, if it is 1 permute the first word and so on..

Here are all the rows and the resulting string for your example

```
0 0 0  James Mitchell Rhodes
0 0 1  James Mitchell R,
0 1 0  James M. Rhodes
0 1 1  James M. R.
1 0 0  J. Mitchell Rhodes
1 0 1  J. Mitchell R.
1 1 0  J. M. Rhodes
1 1 1  J. M. R
```